# Angular-material MatSnackBar default duration time

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular5

Our team is using the MatSnackBar of the Angular Material in the application. Because every one is in charge of different pages there are different durations times of the snackBars of each page. Some set the duration to 2000ms, others to 1000ms and some even made it 3000ms.

I want to get the duration value from a single variable so I can control the duration for all snackBars in one place. Maybe even to dismiss the developers from sending a duration value when calling the snackBar.open function.

```
this.snackBar.open(message, {
  duration: 2000,
});
```

What is the best way for it?

Comment: You're probably looking for a **Singleton Service** that uses a `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: This will force all the developres to inject another service in every page that is using the natSnackBar. Isnt there a nore elegant way?

Comment: That's correct, and there isn't without directly editing the `MatSnackBarModule`, which would be the other option. You'd more or less just add the BehSub there instead of a new service

Comment: Thank you so much.. can you please explain how to do it? What is the BehSub?

Comment: It's the `BehaviorSubject`. It'd be a decent amount of work to be able to embed this in the npm package, especially if you planning on using this for production. Would highly recommended just using the singleton service and not attempting to edit the Material modules

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should set an application-wide [default Snackbar configuration](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview#setting-the-global-configuration-defaults).

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {duration: 2500}}
  ]
})
```

You'll still need to scrub through your existing code and remove instances where an explicit duration is passed, but future code can just say `this.snackbar.open(msg)` without any options.

Comment: This is the right way although my answer to myself :-)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way that worked for me

```
this.snackBar.open("Item added to Cart", "X", {"duration": 2000});
```

So for your case get the value of duration from centralized const variable.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by wrapping the MatSnackBar and using a factory for the dialog.open.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class SnackBarService {
  private config: MatSnackBarConfig;
  constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
this.config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
this.config.duration = 2000;
}
public open(message: string, duration?: number, action?: string) {
this.config = duration ? Object.assign(this.config, { 'duration': duration }) : this.config;
this.snackBar.open(message, action, this.config);
}}
```